# How to make a reverse string using a for loop?

Tags: java, string, return, output, reverse

I need to have my code output the String in reverse order. For example, the output should have "code" return as "edoc". This is what I have done so far.

```
public String reverseString(String str) {
 String res = "";

for (int i = 0; i <= str.length()-1; i++) {
   res = res + str.charAt(i);
 }
  return res;
}
```

Comment: Does this HAVE to use a `for` loop?  Is this java, c# or what?

Comment: Sorry. It's in Java, and yes it has to use a `for` loop.

Comment: OK just as a comment, non-for `new StringBuilder(mystring).reverse().toString()`

Comment: Pick and understand the technique in an answer that augments your "learning" exercise; either a positive or negative for loop.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue with your way of doing it is your taking the n'th character from str and appending it to make it the n'th character of res.

You could fix it like this:

```
public String reverseString(String str) {
   String res = "";

   for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
       res = res + str.charAt(i);
   }
   return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have your concatenation backwards. Try:

```
public String reverseString(String str) {
    String res = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
       res = str.charAt(i) + res;            // Add each char to the *front*
    }
    return res;
}
```

Note also the simpler, canonical, loop termination condition.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class ReverseString {

    //1. using for loop and charAt
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String s="Selenium";
        
        String reverse="";
        for(int i=s.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            reverse=reverse+(s.charAt(i));
        }
        System.out.println(reverse);
}
```

Comment: You should add some commentary to this answer, explaining how it improves on [that provided some time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43148437/10871073) by Jack Gore (if, indeed, it does).