# Reversing a string using for loop giving an error

Tags: arrays, string

I'm trying to assign the elements of string `str[]` to `rev[]` using this code below, but it keeps giving me the error:

> "string subscript out of range" error.

How do I correct this?

```
for (int i = 0; i <= str.length(); i++)
{
    for (int j = str.length(); j >= 0; j--)
    {
        rev[i] = str[j];
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you need nested `for` loops to reverse the string? Think about what `str.length() - j` gives you. Also, you should tag your question with the programming language you are using.

Comment: i'll keep in mind to tag the language. I don't really get what you mean by str.length() - j

Comment: The first iteration of the inner j loop executes this: `str[str.length()]`, which is out of bounds.

Comment: Just use `str.length() - 1` to start with your loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a reverse string using a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43148337/how-to-make-a-reverse-string-using-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 1):

For an array index range from `0` to array `size - 1`.
You don't need two loops to reverse an array.
In java you can do reversal like this:

```
int length = str.length - 1;        
for (int i = 0; i <= str.length-1; i++) {
        rev[length - i] = str[i];
}
```